# Tap installed on audio engine only producing short files

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I am working on an app that allows the user to record audio, play it back while changing the pitch then record what they have done as a separate file.

The code seems to be working but the new file has a duration of only 0.37 seconds (original 5 seconds). 
I am guessing when I write from the buffer it keeps saving over itself, thus leaving me with just the last segment. If this is my issue, how do I append the file instead of writing over it?

```
    let recordSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
    ]


    var outputFile = AVAudioFile()

    let format = NSDateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat="dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let currentFileName = "recording-\(format.stringFromDate(NSDate())).m4a"
    print(currentFileName)

    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    self.url2 = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)

    let inputNode = engine.inputNode
    let bus = 0

    engine.mainMixerNode.installTapOnBus(bus, bufferSize: 2048, format: self.engine.mainMixerNode.inputFormatForBus(0)) {
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in

        do {

            let outputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: self.url2, settings: recordSettings, commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMFormatFloat32, interleaved: false)

            try outputFile.writeFromBuffer(buffer)
            outputFile.framePosition = outputFile.length

        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Error writing %@", error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Updated code creating a file with a duration of 0.0:

```
func play() {

    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(AVAsset(URL: url).duration)
    print("Duration")
    print(duration)

    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)

    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
    do {
        try file.readIntoBuffer(buffer)
    } catch _ {
    }

    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    pitch.pitch = 500


    engine.attachNode(player)
    engine.attachNode(pitch)

    engine.connect(player, to: pitch, format: buffer.format)
    engine.connect(pitch, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

    let format = NSDateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat="dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let currentFileName = "recording-\(format.stringFromDate(NSDate())).m4a"
    print(currentFileName)

    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    self.url2 = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)

    let outputFile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: url2, settings:  [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
    ])

    done = false
    distortion.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: 2048, format: outputFile.processingFormat) {
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) in

        let dataptrptr = buffer.floatChannelData
        let dataptr = dataptrptr.memory
        let datum = dataptr[Int(buffer.frameLength) - 1]
        if self.done && fabs(datum) < 0.000001 {
            print("stopping")
            self.engine.stop()
            return
        }

        do {
            try outputFile.writeFromBuffer(buffer)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Error writing %@", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

        player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, atTime: nil, options: AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferOptions.Loops, completionHandler: {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.done = true
            self.player.stop()
                self.engine.stop()
            print("complete")
            })
        })

    engine.prepare()
    do {
        try engine.start()
        player.play()
    } catch _ {
        print("Play session Error")
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the `installTapOnBus` handler will be called many times: every time the buffer fills up. Think of it as a loop. Thus it makes no sense to create the output file each time through that loop! You want to create the output file *once* and *then* write to it *repeatedly*. Thus, your overall structure needs to look like this:

```
let outfile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: outurl, settings: // ...
node.installTapOnBus(bus, bufferSize: size, format: outfile.processingFormat) {
    (buffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time : AVAudioTime!) in
        do {
            try outfile.writeFromBuffer(buffer)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The other thing to remember is that your buffer will fill-and-write exactly so long as the engine keeps running, so don't stop the engine prematurely (I don't know whether you're doing that, but it's important to keep in mind).

Comment: Thank you for the well written response. It makes a lot of sense, but I am still very new at this. I have updated my code above to follow your advice, but now I am creating files with a duration of 0.0. Could you let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: "Could you let me know where I am going wrong?" No, because so much of your code is not shown. As I said in my answer, starting the engine and running it long enough to produce the sound through the buffer is up to you, but you don't show any of that. If it would help you to see a working example, here's the code from the tap example in my book (see `doButton5`): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p655AVAudioEngineTest/AVAudioEngineTest/ViewController.swift